# How can I monitor changes to an online PDF simply?

Tags: pdf

How can I get an alert when changes to an online PDF have occurred? Simple solutions will carry the day.

Answer (score 2):

Do this once:

```
wget -O file.pdf http://example.com/file.pdf
md5sum file.pdf > file.md5
```

The set this up in a cron job:

```
wget -O file.pdf http://example.com/file.pdf
md5sum -c file.md5
```

Of course, you'll need to modify the paths in the code sample so that the `wget` and md5sum commands can find the downloaded file. If md5sum does no report OK, then you know the file has changed. Have your script send an alert email or take some other action. (You didn't mention your OS so I answered on how I would do it on Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, after providing my first answer I found a couple of websites that do this. I've never used any of these so I can't speak to their reputation or reliability. I used `free website content monitoring` as the Google search term.

- [ChangeDetect](http://www.changedetect.com/)
- [TheWebWatcher](http://www.thewebwatcher.com/)
- [WatchThatPage](http://www.watchthatpage.com/)

Comment: currently I am using "Changes Meter" in Mac

Answer (score 0):

Super easy to do with [Visualobserver.com](https://www.visualobserver.com)

Works like this:

1. Add URL of PDF
2. Select Part you want to monitor
3. Select frequency (How often you want to monitor?)
4. Select Alerts (When do you want to get alerted?